# How can I add events on my calendar view in Android app?

Tags: android, events, calendar, android-calendar, android-event

I have an app that has a `CalendarView` like this in the photo:
[image]

And I want that it could take "events" with date and description from a list of events and put a little point (or something like that) in the calendar corrisponding of the date;
For example, if I have events on 7,10,11 of this month, the `CalendarView` must be like this:
[image]

I don't mind about the part under calendar,